# ThreadPoolTaskScheduler internals - does the parameter order of Task.WaitAll() change the order of execution?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I've run across a case like the following in my work. (I've kinda simplified it a bit for this thread's purpose)

Here's the code (a .net core console app) :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int numberOfTasks = 15;
        var taskArray = new Task[numberOfTasks];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            var temp = i;
            taskArray[i] = Task.Run(() => SingleTest(temp));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED!!!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void SingleTest(int temp)
    {
        var signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{temp} T1 started");
            signal.Set();
            Console.WriteLine($"{temp} T1 finished");
        });

        var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{temp} T2 started");
            signal.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine($"{temp} T2 finished");
        });

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        //Task.WaitAll(t2, t1);
        Console.WriteLine($"{temp}: Both tasks finished");
    }
}
```

When I run this code with 8 or more loop iterations, none of the T1 tasks start before ALL the T2 tasks have been started, which seems really weird. My question is why would this happen? I would have expected the tasks to start in a totally random order.

Here's the start of the output for a sample execution (8 iterations):

```
5 T2 started
7 T2 started
3 T2 started
0 T2 started
4 T2 started
6 T2 started
2 T2 started
1 T2 started
1 T1 started
1 T1 finished
1 T2 finished
1: Both tasks finished
...
```

When I change the order of the parameters in the Task.WaitAll() call (as in the commented out line), the behaviour is quite different, where the tasks are started in a (seemingly) random order (Most T1 tasks seem to start earlier than their T2 equivalents, however at least some T2 tasks are started before all the T1 tasks have been completed)

Sample output:

```
7 T1 started
5 T1 started
5 T1 finished
4 T1 started
4 T1 finished
1 T1 started
1 T1 finished
6 T1 started
6 T1 finished
3 T1 started
3 T1 finished
1 T2 started --For example,this T2 task was started before some of the T1 tasks
0 T1 started
0 T1 finished
2 T1 started
2 T1 finished
4 T2 started
4 T2 finished
3 T2 started
1 T2 finished
7 T1 finished
0 T2 started
0 T2 finished
2 T2 started
6 T2 started
6 T2 finished
3 T2 finished
1: Both tasks finished
```

So, what I'm wondering is, what is happening under the hood to create such a behaviour?

Comment: These Console.WriteLine calls are made without synchronization so can occur at any time. The only guarantee the AutoResetEvent provides is that "T2 finished" message is always displayed after "T1 started" for a specific invocation of SingleTest().

Comment: I'm not submitting an answer, because I'm not entirely sure I'm correct. So, I'm curious to see what answers are submitted! But based on my understanding of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/), it looks like it depends on what thread the task gets queued to. Therefore, the task isn't going to get executed until the thread has availability, which explains why there is no order. Meaning, if you run it 10 times, you'll probably see 10 different results. It has everything to do with when the thread has availability to execute the process.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting. So, the ```SingleTest()``` calls are actually being executed in order, but the ```Console.WriteLine()``` isn't?

Comment: No, the SingleTest calls are not ordered in any way either.  Exactly when a Task.Run target starts executing is unpredictable.

Comment: I guess, need to see implementation of Task.WaitAll  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,72b6b3fa5eb35695 and pay attention on reverse loop inside

Comment: @HansPassant The autoresetevent is there for another reason actually, it was needed in my actual use case so I've put it in the simplified version as well. Also, the issue in the first case happens consistently. When using Task.WaitAll(t1,t2), all the T2 tasks were started before any of the T1 tasks were started in all of my test runs (with 8 or more loop iterations). In my actual use case, there were thousands of event handlers with code similar to the SingleTest method where the same issue occurred.

Comment: @ArtsiomChe This seems to be the cause of the issue, thanks :) I've delayed the call to Task.WaitAll in the SingleTest method until both tasks were completed to see if the task starting order would change and it did. It seems like none of the tasks created in the SingleTest method are started until all the SingleTest calls have been blocked (since SingleTest calls run on the thread pool as well I guess). Hence they are all inlined by the reverse loop you mentioned.